# How to implement a optimised hybrid sorting algorithm of quiksort and insertion sort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

I want to switch to insertion sort for smaller arrays and quicksort for larger arrays. Switching to insertion sort may reduce the number the recursions.
**I want to know maximum size of array where I can switch to insertion sort.**

Here is implemention of quicksort and insertion sort. For array length < 9 insertion sort is used. 
https://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/8/

Even we know  Dual pivot quicksort uses insertion to sort array smaller arrays of length < 27
http://codeblab.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf

**PS - Java uses Dual pivot quicksort to sort primitivs types**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question here. At some point you are making the decision to switch from quick-sort to insertion sort in order to save memory, but sacrifice speed. Insertion sort is O(n^2) while Quick-sort is O(nlogn), but quicksort uses recursion and is therefore relatively memory intensive. Depending on how you want the program balanced, decide at what point you save memory by slowing it down It's up to you.

Comment: What I know is for some array length < n insertion sort performs faster than quicksort. I want to know that n

Comment: There is no fixed value, it depends on a ton of factors like the language your in and what processor you're on, but somewhere around 16 or so is a pretty safe bet.